# Trimming trailing whitespace from every line in a multi-line string using replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

Please explain why in this expression, the replacement only occurs once, at the end of the string.

```
"1  \n3  \n5  ".replaceAll(" +$", "x") // => "1  \n3  \n5x"
```

According to the [Java 7 docs for Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), 
`$` is supposed to match the end of a line, and `\z` match the end of input (the string).

My goal is to replace trailing whitespace at the end of every line in a string. The `"x"` replacement is merely a way to better visualize what is being replaced.

I would think a regular expression and String.replaceAll ought to be able to do this. If `replaceAll` is not able to perform this operation, please suggest a concise alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To replace the trailing whitespace of each line, you need to use the `(?m)` (multi-line) modifier.

```
"1  \n3  \n5  ".replaceAll("(?m) +$", "x") //=> "1x\n3x\n5x"
```

**Note**: This modifier makes the `^` and `$` match at the start and end of each line.

Answer (score 4):

hwnd's answer is indeed the most concise way to do it. However, especially if the pattern is to be matched many, many times, I'd like to suggest an alternative that is faster. Yes, it's called precompiling the pattern! (In contrast, `String#replaceAll` recompiles the pattern on each invocation.)

```
private static final Pattern LINE_END_SPACES = Pattern.compile(" +$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

public static String stripLineEndSpaces(String str) {
    return LINE_END_SPACES.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
}
```

Yes, it looks more clunky, and that's because Java doesn't have regexp literals. I wish it did, but then people will want JSON literals, XML literals (think E4X), XPath expression literals, `printf` format string literals, SQL statement literals, etc., and then people will be asking when the madness will stop. :-)

Comment: Don't you instead just get people asking for those, plus regexp literals? ;-)